# Is there any pointer feature in java to pass the byte array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to divide a byte array into 3 parts and process them one by one

The first 120 data array is filled in callback function of a Bluetooth device read request, so it's impossible for me to change

```
byte[] data = new byte[120];

------

    byte[] buf = new byte[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        System.arraycopy(data, i * 40, packetBuffer, 0, 40);

        processDataStream(buf);
    }
```

If in c/c++, I can use pointer so no need to call copy. 
In Java,  is arraycopy the best way?  is there any more efficient way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you'd just specify an offset and provide it to your method:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[40];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    processDataStream(buf, i * 40);
}
```

Then you only need to apply it:

```
processDataStream(byte[] buf, int offset) {
    for (int i = offset; i < offset + 40; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply,  yes,  I know offset should work well.  only want to know if there a pointer way.  seems no,  right?

Comment: I don't know a way with C-like pointers. There's object structures working similarly, but these use offsets under the hood as well. String would be an example.